# Algorithm on an ordered collection of strings

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assessment to do and I'm not good at programming. I can search for the algorithms and see how they are done, but in my case I have ordered collection of strings and somehow I have to use the get method.
I have these two classes that must not be changed:

```
public class SearchTest {

/**
 * Test program for the Search class.
 * Put whatever tests you like in the body of the method.
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException of error reading the input
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Don't change this line
    final Search search = new Search();

    // You can set this to any of the text files in the data folder
    final FileStrings strings = new FileStrings("data/small.txt");

    // add your tests here
    System.out.println(search.longestWord(strings));

}
}
```

and

```
public class FileStrings implements StringList {
/** Underlying list of elements */
private final ArrayList<String> elements;

/** Number of calls to get() since the last call to resetCount() */
private int count;

/**
 * Create a list containing the lines of a text file.
 * @param fileName name of a text file of strings, in order
 * @throws java.io.IOException on input error
 */
public FileStrings(String fileName) throws IOException {
    elements = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            elements.add(line);
        }
    }
    count = 0;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this list.
 * This method takes constant time.
 * @return the number of elements in this list
 */
@Override
public int size() {
    return elements.size();
}

/**
 * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
 * This method takes constant time.
 * @param i position in the list, between 0 and size()-1
 * @return the element at the position i
 */
@Override
public String get(int i) {
    count++;
    return elements.get(i);
}

/**
 * Reset the count field.
 */
public void resetCount() {
    count = 0;
}

/**
 * Getter for count.
 * @return number of calls to get() since the last resetCount()
 */
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
}
```

And my first task is to find the longest word from the given file list.
This is my attempt(I know it's wrong, but can't follow examples, because the solutions I see use the array directly):

```
public class Search {

/**
 * Returns the index of the longest string in the list.
 * If there are several string of this length, the 
 * indexed returned is the that of the first.
 * @param a list of strings, in ascending order
 * @return position of an entry with the longest string in the list
 */
public int longestWord(StringList a) {
   int i=0;
   int longestWord=0;
  String nextWord=a.get(i+1);
  String previousWord=a.get(i);
 while (i < a.size() ) {
      if (nextWord.length()>previousWord.length()){
         longestWord = i;
      }
  i = i + 1;

  }
    return longestWord;
}
```

The result should be "14", the world "because" is the 15th word and is the longest. I hope you can help me with this!
[list of words](https://pastebin.com/gXw8Bb1M)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I suggest that you practice some debugging skills. These are critical as you become a programmer. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips.

Comment: Hint: You increment 'i', but you never actually get the word at that position. There are more problems in your routine, so I concur with @Code-Apprentice: Use this as an opportunity to practice debugging.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will keep suffering :D

Comment: Ivan, if you learn to use the appropriate tools, you can greatly decrease the suffering and learn a lot along the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Search {

/**
 * Returns the index of the longest string in the list.
 * If there are several string of this length, the 
 * indexed returned is the that of the first.
 * @param a list of strings, in ascending order
 * @return position of an entry with the longest string in the list
 */
public int longestWord(StringList a) {
  int length=a.get(0).length();
  int i=0;
  int longestWord=0;
  while (i<a.size()){
      if (a.get(i).length()>length){
          length=a.get(i).length();
          longestWord=i;

      }
       i = i + 1;
  }
    return longestWord;
}
```

managed to do it :P

Comment: Thanks for updating your own question. Just a stylistic suggestion: instead of a while() it is more understandable if you used a 'for' like this: 'for (int i = 0; i < a.size(), i++) {... } . This keeps the loop parameters neatly in one place.